# Installing hawtio 1.4.27 on JBoss Fuse 6.0 giving error

Tags: maven, osgi, apache-camel, jbossfuse, hawtio

I am trying to install the latest hawtio 1.4.27 version on JBoss Fuse 6.0, but it seems that it gives error while doing so.

Since this is server machine I have created an offline repository and added the below entries in the pom file for the offline repository

```
<descriptor>mvn:io.hawt/hawtio-karaf/1.4.27/xml/features</descriptor>
```

and

```
<feature>hawtio</feature>
```

After that I executed these commands in fuse console

```
features:addurl mvn:io.hawt/hawtio-karaf/1.4.27/xml/features
features:install hawtio
```

While installing it gives following error:

```
Error executing command: Could not start bundle mvn:io.hawt/hawtio-karaf-terminal/1.4.27/war in feature(s) hawtio-karaf-terminal-1.4.27: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve bundle revision io.hawt.hawtio-karaf-terminal [238.0] because it is exposed to package 'jline' from bundle revisions jline [239.0] and org.apache.karaf.shell.console [15.0] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  io.hawt.hawtio-karaf-terminal [238.0]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=jline)(version>=2.11.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=jline
  jline [239.0]

Chain 2:
  io.hawt.hawtio-karaf-terminal [238.0]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline)(version>=2.2.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline; uses:=jline
    export: osgi.wiring.package=jline
  org.apache.karaf.shell.console [15.0]
```

What I am missing? Please help.

*Note: I tried installing hawtio 1.4.1 on JBoss Fuse 6.0 and it installs fine and runs successfully*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was running the wrong command.
As it was mention in hawtio site, if you are on ServiceMix 4.5 then you should install hawtio-core instead of hawtio
Following command to be executed.

```
features:addurl mvn:io.hawt/hawtio-karaf/1.4.27/xml/features
features:install hawtio-core
```

Here's [a link](http://hawt.io/getstarted/) to hawtio site. Under "Using Fuse, Fabric8, Apache Karaf or Apache Servicemix" section NOTE is provided.

Comment: Great, that you solved your problem. Please mark the question as answered.